# Per user / Per machine installation differences

Tags: windows, installation, installer

What is the different between "Per-User" and "Per-Machine" installation type with respect to "closing the running applications" before upgrade.

I understand in "Per User" mode., the user gets a prompt to close the already running applications. Otherwise the installer automatically schedules a reboot.

How the same scenario is handled in case of "Per Machine" scenario considering if multiple users logged in and using the same application when upgrade happens.

I could not find the exact answer for this around the internet. So Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

When an application installed per-user, its files (including executable ones) are installed within a user's profile. Therefore every user has its own set of files and no one except this user (and those who could get access to his profile) could run the executable file. In this case upgrading is happening only for this user and it's enough to close a process running under this user.

In case of a per-machine installation the application files are shared between all users and to update the file the installer should close all running instances of the application under every user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But as far as I know, if an application is installed in Per machine mode ., and if multiple users are using at the same time... there is no prompt to close the application from all users. Is my understanding is correct ?

Comment: In general the installer will show a message that it needs to close a process or do a reboot only to a user who do the uninstallation.

Comment: Yes... But the same is not happening when we do the upgrades via silent installation. :( from command line. Is there any way to achieve the similar behavior?

Comment: Silent installations will not ask anyone about anything, that the point. It would be easier to answer if you'd tell what is your main issue.